# Can you Sustain Spells/Activations from maze or other extradimensions?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, extradimensional-space, sustained-powers

In my most recent game of P2e, my spellcaster used a [*summon fey*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=322) spell to bring forth an ally with a small chance of doing a ton of damage. The enemy spellcaster's response was to cast [*maze*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=187) on me. (I'm also generally a healer, so it made sense for them to remove me from the board for a time regardless).

Am I able to [sustain my spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=73) from my new home for the foreseeable future? Obviously I cannot give them any new orders, but I feel like I might be able to give them more time to follow my last instructions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You Can Sustain in a *Maze*

> You transport the target into an extradimensional maze of eldritch origin and trap it there. Once each turn, the target can spend 1 action to attempt a Survival check or Perception check against your spell DC to escape the maze.

Nothing in the effect of the *[maze](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=187)* spell  prevents the target from taking the Sustain action, it just allows them the option to attempt escape for 1 action. Likewise there is no limitation in the Sustain action for this circumstance, so you can Sustain while in a *maze*.

### Summoned Minions Acting Alone

> Minions are creatures that directly serve another creature.
> Your minion acts on your turn in combat, once per turn, when
> you spend an action to issue it commands. For an animal
> companion, you Command an Animal; **for a minion that’s a
> spell or magic item effect, like a summoned minion, you
> Sustain the effect** (page 419); if not otherwise specified, you
> issue a verbal command as a single action with the auditory
> and concentrate traits. If given no commands, minions use
> no actions except to defend themselves or to escape obvious
> harm.

Creatures with the [minion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109) trait usually only act as commanded, to defend themselves, or to escape obvious harm, but the [summoned](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=154) trait is a bit more generous:

> A creature called by a spell or effect gains the summoned trait... It generally attacks your enemies to the best of its ability. **If you can communicate with it, you can attempt to command it**, but the GM determines the degree to which it follows your commands.

Summoned creatures often might not understand the summoner's commands (such as most aberrant [entities](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=321) or many [elementals](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=320)), but instead they have a generic behavior to attack your enemies to the best of their ability when not otherwise commanded.

Answer (score 1):

### You can sustain spells while banished, but a minion will only defend itself without a new command each round

The sustian action has the following requirements:

> **Requirements** You have at least one spell active with a sustained duration, and you are not fatigued.

There is no requirement to be in range, or even on the same plane. Neither is there such a requirement in the rules for range or duration of spells. You therefore are good to sustain your spell.

However, while you are banished, the summoned fey will not act on old commands. The fey has the [summoned](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=154) trait, which includes the [minion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109) trait, and that says:

> Your minion acts on your turn in combat, **once per turn, when you spend an action to issue it commands** [...] for a minion that's a spell or magic item effect, like a summoned minion, you Sustain a Spell or Sustain an Activation; if not otherwise specified, you issue a verbal command as a single action with the **auditory** and concentrate traits. **If given no commands, minions use no actions except to defend themselves** or to escape obvious harm. If left unattended for long enough, typically 1 minute, mindless minions usually don't act, animals follow their instincts, and sapient minions act how they please.

It is not otherwise specified here, so while you Sustain the spell, you normally are sissuing auditory commands to your summoned minion to make it act. Your old command is not going to work, as you need to spend a Sustain action **once per turn** to make the minion act, and there is no way to issue a new command as part of your Sustain action, as you are not there and the minion needs to be able to hear you:

> An action with the auditory trait can be successfully performed only if the creature using the action can speak or otherwise produce the required sounds. A spell or effect with the auditory trait has its effect only **if the target can hear it**.

It may still worthwhile to sustain the spell: You only need one action a turn try try and escape the *maze*, and can manage to do so with a single critical success, or with two normal successes that are not interrupted by a critical failure, so it is possible that you will be back in action before the summon effect runs out, and can resume issuing commands.